# Ionic on-drag-over directive

Tags: angularjs, mobile, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, gesture

I am trying to call a function when an element is dragged over. That is, when your finger slides to touch it, like a piano roll hitting each key. on-drag only calls for the item you touch down on as you drag away from it.

Is there some way to accomplish this with regular ionic directives?